# Asp.Net Drop Down List

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webforms

Como faço pra passar uma `dropdownlist` por parâmetro? Tentei passar, por exemplo:

```
public void preencheDrop(string SQL, WebControl x)
{
    método aqui. 
}
```

mas não consegui. Esse método eu só quero facilitar minha vida pra poder preencher mais de um `drop` e não ter que ficar toda hora copiando código.

Comment: Troque WebControl por System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList

Answer (score 2):

Veja se isso realmente te atende. É só você fazer as devidas alterações.

```
public bool preencheTipo_Usuario(DropDownList dl)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendLine("select ");
            sb.AppendLine("codtipo, descricao_tipo");
            sb.AppendLine("from tbl_tipo_usuario ");

            SqlConnection conexao = new SqlConnection();
            conexao.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conectDarf"].ConnectionString;
            this.cmd = new SqlCommand(sb.ToString(), conexao);

            try
            {
                conexao.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                dl.DataSource = dr;
                dl.DataTextField = "descricao_tipo";
                dl.DataValueField = "codtipo";
                dl.DataBind();

                dl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--- SELECIONE ---", "-1"));
            }
            catch (Exception excecao)
            {
                Erro = excecao.Message;
                return false;
            }
            finally
            {
                conexao.Close();

            }

            return true;
        }
```

Comment: Opa , vou testar e já volto pra saber o resultado